# Sleep/Suspend and WOL on FreeNAS

Tags: truenas, wake-on-lan, acpi

I am trying to figure out how to get FreeNAS 8 to sleep when inactive and, ideally, wake on lan activity (or, less ideally, wake on a WOL magic packet). However, as I've tried to search for information on how to do this, almost all discussions seem to be centered on FreeNAS 7. Also, the tools included in FreeBSD to do this seem to be missing (i.e. acpiconf, etc.).

Is there a way to get FreeNAS 8 to sleep and wake so that I don't have to leave the server running all the time? Given its usage level, it seems a waste to have the server running constantly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get FreeNAS to do a suspend, because AFAIK they didn't compile the necessary ACPI stuff into the system.

Actually I think I've been wrong here!
I just found [acpi feature request](http://support.freenas.org/ticket/107) and [trac commit log](http://support.freenas.org/changeset/7548/freenas).

It sounds a little vague though, so you may want to ask at [FreeNAS Dev Mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/freenas-devel)

Comment: Is there a reasonably easy way to build a custom FreeNAS build with ACPI on? If so, what OS would be needed to host the build? Would OS X work? I am guessing it would have a better shot than Linux...

Comment: I wrote an edit. might have been wrong after all.

Comment: Let us here know when you find an answer, since information on this is sparse and contradicting. Remember, it may help others, too if there is a definite answer here.

Comment: Any update on this? Looks like the old feature request links are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can shut your freenas down by executing a `plink.exe` command. (Google "plink" to find the download area.)

If you can enable `ssh` access to your freenas, you can execute `plink -ssh -pw [PASSWORD] [root]@[IP OF FREENAS] shutdown -p now` where `PASSWORD` is the password of the freenas root user and `IP OF FREENAS` is the IP address of your freenas.

To wake up freenas, you can use a tool called `wol.exe`. If you use `wol.exe` followed by the mac-address of your network card it sends a wake-on-Lan package. (Google for "`wol.exe`".)

Both commands can be scripted and scheduled by the windows task scheduler.